# PowerShell Error occurred on "Azure Container Instances"

Tags: azure, docker, powershell

These code can run on "Docker" on Windows 10.
But these code can not run on "Azure Container Instances" on Windows 10

(command's parameters are omitted)

---

Connect-AzAccount

Connect-PnPOnline

New-PnPTenantSite

New-AzStorageContext

Set-AzStorageBlobContent

---

if these code run on "Azure Container Instances", this error below occurred on the azure terminal. Can someone know what is reason and issue?

---

The Win32 internal error "No process is on the other end of the pipe" 0xE9 occurred while getting console output buffer information. Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.

Answer (score 0):

> The Win32 internal error "No process is on the other end of the pipe" 0xE9 occurred while getting console output buffer information. Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.

This issue shows that version (Win32) of window throwing error. Because of the version of windows of the Azure Container instance was different from local.

#### Ways to fix the issue:

- Use win64 version of Windows Azure Container Instance.
  [image]
- Make sure you are using latest PowerShell modules. If not update the latest Az PowerShell Modules to access the Azure resources.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!! I will confirm that environment on Azure as soon as possible.